# My object keeps rotating on the X axis when playing the animation

Tags: animation, 3d-view

[image: Before playing]

[image: after playing]

What is the solution for this object to stay in its rotation while playing?

Comment: Does it still rotate when you click on the little lock on the right of the field ?

Comment: I got it fixed though. But the lock isn’t working

Comment: could you elaborate on how you did it ?

Answer (score 0):

I just manually put the right orientation in in the dope sheet. Every single second.